# How to get Python on Windows access in Msys2?

Tags: python-3.x, msys2

I have python on Windows.
I want to access this python on Msys2.
When i type python i am getting error python: command not found

- I have installed Msys2.
- I have set environment path for both Python and Msys2 (first python paths and then Msys2 paths).

Still i am unable to access Python on Windows in Msys2.

Comment: I would install python from MSYS2 itself. Otherwise, your problem is that MSYS2 disregards the system-wide PATH (run `msys2_shell -full-path` to make it respect it).